# How do I automate the removal of DCR Associations on problem VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

I have a couple of VMs that send more than several million events to their log analytics workspaces in a matter of days which runs up the cost of monitoring them exponentially.

I have the AMA setup on these VMs using a few DCRs.

Is there a way I can automatically remove the DCR association on any of my VMs that produce too many events within a certain time range?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell command: Remove-AzDataCollectionRule

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/remove-azdatacollectionrule?view=azps-8.1.0

If you want to automate it. You can run the powershell command from a runbook: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution

You will need to create an alert that will trigger the execution of the runbook.